# Estimate possibility for interval using central limit theorem

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

Suppose Y ~ Poisson(100). Using the central limit theorem to estimate P(80 ≤ Y ≤ 120)

The answer is P (80−100)/10 ≤ X1+···+X100−100µ /√ 100 σ ≤ (120−100)/ 10.

I think since they assume that 100 is large enough to use the central limit theory, they used Z = (x - µ) / σ  to standardize distribution. However, I learned that when you are dealing with sampling distribution and n is large enough, you use Z = (x - µ) / (σ /√n). So I was wondering if there is a way to know when to use which Z.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried using Z = (x - µ) / (σ /√n) instead of Z= (x - µ) / σ  so my answer was different.

Comment: What is the relationship between $Y$ and $X_i$?

Comment: Y = X1 + X2 + ... X100 where Xi's are independent Poisson (1) random variables.